# How to modify android x86 system.img properly?

Tags: android, linux, mount

I was trying to modify the android emulator system.img file. I want to start android emulators from the modified system.img.

I tried the https://github.com/anestisb/android-simg2img  approach, with error "Invalid sparse file format at header magi"

The exact file is "Android/Sdk/system-images/android-26/google_apis/x86/system.img", its an official google img downloaded from sdkmanager.

```
$ file /home/user/Android/Sdk/system-images/android-26/google_apis/x86/system.img 
./system.img: DOS/MBR boot sector; partition 1 : ID=0xee, start-CHS (0x0,0,2), end-CHS (0x146,155,21), startsector 1, 5246975 sectors, extended partition table (last)
$ fdisk -lu /home/user/Android/Sdk/system-images/android-26/google_apis/x86/system.img 

Disk /home/user/Android/Sdk/system-images/android-26/google_apis/x86/system.img: 2.5 GiB, 2686451712 bytes, 5246976 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disklabel type: gpt
Disk identifier: 9C0C82F8-6E6F-46F9-AFC8-A09D908DAB24

Device                     Start     End Sectors  Size Type
/home/huya/tmp/system.img1  2048 5244927 5242880  2.5G Linux filesystem
```

How to add some files to this .img file and start an emulator from it?
Basically I want to run a customized emulator with some file modified, any other approaches are welcomed.

Answer (score 2):

As can be seen on the output of your commands, Android Emulator images are no longer sparse images, but rather full disk images containing a single partition.

You can modify the contents of that single partition simply by mounting it directly through a loopback device:

```
mount -o loop,offset=1048576 system.img /mnt
```

The offset for the partition can be found using parted:

```
parted system.img unit B print
```

1048576 bytes seems to be the offset for all official images.

You can then edit the contents of the filesystem under `/mnt` and just `umount /mnt` when done.
Do remember to backup the image you're editing beforehand.

---

### Safer method

Alternatively, and arguably much safer and tidy, you can modify the contents of system and vendor images through ADB (Android Debug Bridge) after launching the Android Emulator with the `-writable-system` option:

```
emulator -avd myavd -writable-system
```

Then run:

```
adb root && adb remount
```

Which will run ADB with root privileges and remount all partitions as read-write. You can then drop to a `adb shell` to edit at will, or copy files to the device with `adb push`.

Your modifications will be kept in QEMU QCOW images (`system.img.qcow2`, `vendor.img.qcow2`) inside your AVD directory (e.g. `~/.android/avd/myavd.avd`).