# How to modify android x86 system.img properly (2023)?

Tags: android, linux, android-emulator, android-source, mount

A few years ago, I was able to easy execute the method described in this [resolution (2019)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58603606/how-to-modify-android-x86-system-img-properly). However, when I attempted to test it again today and tried to mount the image, I encountered the following error:

```
# mount -o loop,offset=1048576 system.img /mnt

mount: /mnt: wrong fs type, bad option, bad superblock on /dev/loop2, missing codepage or helper program, or other error.
```

Consequently, I investigated whether there had been any changes to the system.img image:

```
file system.img

system.img: DOS/MBR boot sector; partition 1: ID=0xee, start-CHS (0x0,0,2), end-CHS (0x15c,71,43), startsector 1, 5595135 sectors, extended partition table (last entry)
```

The reason for this investigation is due to the fact that over time, this image underwent several format changes. Initially, system.img was a VMS Alpha executable and could be unpacked using "unyaffs." Later on, it was converted to ext4, with the image becoming sparse. Subsequently, there was another migration, this time to full disk images containing partitions.

I also performed a test to check if the offset had been modified. I noticed that, as of the year 2023, all official images still appear to maintain the value of `1048576`.

```
parted system.img unit B print

Model:  (file)
Disk /root/system.img: 2864709632B
Sector size (logical/physical): 512B/512B
Partition Table: gpt
Disk Flags:

Number  Start     End          Size         File System  Name    Flags
 1      1048576B  2097151B     1048576B                  vbmeta
 2      2097152B  2863661055B  2861563904B               super
```

Lastly, I conducted one final test:

```
simg2img system.img simg2img system.raw.img

Invalid sparse file format at header magic
Failed to read sparse file
```

I am documenting the resolution process for this issue because I have already invested many hours in it. I conducted tests on two different Linux systems (Ubuntu and Debian - latest stable versions) and on Mac Ventura, but so far, I have not found a viable solution. If anyone has other ideas for resolving this problem, I would greatly appreciate the assistance.